# PHP Compress video from Gopro, best way?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I develop a website for hosting videos from GoPro (mp4 files often in HD)

I would like how to compress video after upload.
Acutally, on website you can upload video and watch it but she are so fat and its not possible to watch it ...

I see ffmpeg-php but i don't see how to compress with her API.

the best way, it's compress to unique format like flv ? or to ogv/webM/mp4 to used html 5  ?

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot,

Regards

Comment: See the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for a good start.

Comment: If you are not familiar with the ffmpeg extension you could try with this object oriented wrapper built around the ffmpeg binary https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the exec(); function in your server, you can use FFMPEG following this easy Tutorial, http://www.slideshare.net/ProdigyView/ffmpeg-basics-for-php-tutorial

I think that FFMpeg is the best and easy way to work with video files in php.